# Char array print more than I wanted in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

Why would it print extra "COMMAND /desktop/document/myfilename" at end of char array command?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char c_header[] = "COMMAND /desktop/document/myfilename \r\n\r\n";

    char command[8];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
        command[i] = c_header[i];
    }
    command[7] = 's';

    printf( "command =%s\n", command);

}
```

Output

```
command =COMMANDsCOMMAND /desktop/document/myfilename 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You never terminate your string with a `'\0'`

Comment: No `'\0'` in `command`: it is not a string without it. You can't use it **as a string** with library functions expecting a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in [c](/questions/tagged/c) are terminated by `\0`. If you attempt to treat an array of characters that isn't terminated by `\0` as a string (e.g., `printf`ing it), it will just overrun until you hit the next `\0` that happens to be in your heap.

To make a long story short, you need to explicitly make sure you have a `\0` at the end of your string:

```
/* Added an extra char for the '\0' */
char command[9]; 

for (size_t i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
    command[i] = c_header[i];
}
command[7] = 's';
command[8] = '\0';
```

Comment: I suspect that there may be a duplicate or two for this issue:((

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the string with `<'\0'> or NULL` or the integer `0`.

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer, not the null terminator that belongs at the end of a string.